# Iterate over list in embedded Elixir

Tags: list, elixir

I am currently trying out embedded elixir (in my case .html.eex files). I know how to render elixir hashes, but I couldn't figure out how I create a content showing all items inside a list. In Ruby it would work like this:

```
<% array.each do |item| %>
    <p> <%= item %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Elixir equivalent is

```
<%= for item <- list do %>
  <p><%= item %></p>
<% end %>
```

Note that you have to use a `<%=` in front of the `for` in Elixir.

Comment: "for loop needs a ="?  You mean the <%= on the opening tag?

Comment: Yes, the opening tag!

Comment: I tried to make it clearer. You're welcome to suggest an edit if you can think of a better way to express this! :)

Comment: @PatrickOscity No worries; I was just trying to confirm I was understanding you correctly is all.

Comment: I think you miss a "@" in front of list here.

Answer (score 13):

I was curious if this were possible using the [`Enum`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html) module, since Patrick Oscity's answer relies [`Comprehensions`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) which look to be just a wrapper for the [`Enum`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html) module.

The answer is yes. I first tried with [`Enum.each`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#each/2). Which mysteriously only printed `ok` to the screen, but that's what [`Enum.each`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) does; it always returns the `:ok` atom.

I figured [`Enum.map`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) would be a better shot since it returns a list of results. Take a look:

```
<%= Enum.map(@list, fn(item) -> %>
  <p><%= item %></p>
<% end) %>
```

`EEx` works almost the same as `ERB`. In your `ERB` example you were passing a "block", which is analogous to a lambda or anonymous function, to the `each` function. In my `EEx` example the `fn (item) ->` takes the place of `do |item|`.

So now, not only are you able to iterate over [`Lists`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/List.html), but you're able to experiment with a wider variety of functions that take an anonymous function that manipulates the template.

Comment: Indeed, it does work very similar to `ERB` stuff :) 
One thing though - it should be `<%= Enum.map(@list, fn(item) -> %>` ;)